# RSelenium web scraping always returns Null

Tags: web-scraping, imdb, rselenium

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to crap the movie budget data from IMDb. Here is my code:

```
budget=vector()
for(i in 1:50){
remDr$navigate('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?sort=moviemeter,asc&start=1&title_type=feature&year=2011,2011')
webElems=remDr$findElements('css selector','.wlb_lite+ a')
webElems[[i]]$clickElement()
b=remDr$findElements('css selector','.txt-block:nth-child(11)')
b_text=unlist(lapply(b, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
if(is.null(b_text)==T){
  budget=c(budget,'NULL')
  }

if(is.null(b_text)==F){budget=c(budget,'NULL')}
print(b_text)
}
```

On each page there are 50 movies. I want to click every link one by one and collect the corresponding budget data. If I do not run the code in loop, the code works well. But the code always returns 'Null' when I run it in a loop. I am afraid that is because the pages do not load completely in the loop. I tried to use 'setTimeout' and 'setImplicitWaitTimeout' commands but they do not work well. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

> `Sys.sleep(time in seconds)`

for each loop instead of setTimeout.

That has solved problems like yours to me.

Comment: Thank you! I tried Sys.sleep and it does work! The thing is whether is there a way for R to detect whether a webpage is loaded or not?

Comment: I guess it is intuitive in RSelelnium. Once you navigate to a page and the next code line is executed only after a webpage is loaded. But Sys.sleep gives extra time. I guess!! I'm not sure